# How to stop camel dynamic route on exception

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

How do I stop a camel route when there is an exception. My dynamic route is consuming jms and sending to reactive endpoint.

```
camelContext.addRoutes(New GenerateRoute());
```

Route generator class is as below:

```
public class GenerateRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() {
    from("jms:queue:myQueue")
        .toF("reactive-streams:myStream").setId("myRoute");
}}
```

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai yes, I want my route to permanently "stop" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    from("jms:queue:myQueue")
            .routeId("myRoute")
            .doTry()
                .toF("reactive-streams:myStream")
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .process(exchange -> exchange.getFromEndpoint().stop())
            .end();
```

Comment: You mean doCatch() instead of doFinally() correct? Since I need to stop the route only when there is an exception.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I believe this will still loose one message from jms queue correct? If yes, is there a way to add "transacted"?

Comment: ok thank you! one more question... is the .routeId at correct place if I want to start the route again at later point?

Comment: How do I add transaction in this so that the message that caused the exception is not consumed and stays in the jms queue?

Comment: I have added followup question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743621/how-to-setup-transaction-in-camel-jms-route

Answer (score 2):

You can use `handled` and `continued`. in the `onException` clause. "Continued allows you to both handle and continue routing in the original route as if the exception did not occur." if `continued` is false the routing won't go back to the original route.

DSL:

```
<onException>
    <exception>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</exception>
    <continued><constant>false</constant></continued>
</onException>
```

Java:

```
onException(IllegalArgumentException.class).continued(fasle);
```

Refer to: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html#

Comment: Will this terminate only the generated route correct?I updated my question with the code I have. Does this look right as below?

Comment: `public class GenerateRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    onException(Exception.class).process(exchange -> {
            System.out.println("handling ex");
        }).continued(false);
        
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("jms:queue:myQueue")
            .toF("reactive-streams:myStream").setId("myRoute");
    }
}`

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What `continued` does is in handling the exception. If you want to return the control back to the route then the continued is true otherwise you can set it false. If `handled` is true the occurred exception will be removed in the exchange otherwise it will remain in the exchange and you can still retrieve it from exchange using:

`Throwable caused = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);`
These are

Comment: I can give and example: if the message is read from queue and send to another route like `direct:enrich-message` which enriches the message and then from`direct:enrich-message` you sent it to `direct:send-to-mysystem` where you send it to`reactive-streams:myStream` if you have `continued=true` and `handled=false` in the `onException` clause of `direct:send-to-mysystem` then the exchange will be sent back to `direct:enrich-message` route with the caught exception in the exchange.

Comment: I am looking for a way to completely stop the route so the route doesn't consume from JMS anymore. Basically context.getRoute("myRoute").getConsumer.stop().  As I understand continued(false) will still keep consuming from JMS. Will transacted work in this case?

Comment: Then you need to stop the whole route. See: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html

Comment: Moreover, I think you need to change your question as well.

Comment: See also this: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/lifecycle.html