# How to setup transaction in Camel JMS Route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-jms

How do I setup transaction in JMS route to rollback or not consume a message when an exception occurs. Below is my route. MQ is ActiveMQ.

```
from("jms:queue:myQueue")
        .routeId("myRoute")
        .doTry()
            .toF("reactive-streams:myStream")
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .process(exchange -> exchange.getFromEndpoint().stop())
        .end();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding transacted did the job! Also, had to enable connection pooling and camel-jms-starter (for default factories).

```
from("jms:queue:myQueue?transacted=true")
        .routeId("myRoute")
        .doTry()
            .toF("reactive-streams:myStream")
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .process(exchange -> exchange.getFromEndpoint().stop())
        .end();
```